# kinetic-v3.8.2.js breaks kinetic-v3.6.0.js and kinetic-image-plugin-v1.0.1.js, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to make a kinetic canvas where I can add pictures from another source dynamically and I wanted a grid in the background so I used the kinetic.rect from kinetic v3.8.2.
The images needs to be draggable, from kinetic v.3.6.0, but if I set draggable when having v3.8.2 active it breaks.
"config is undefined" according to FireBug.
"img.kinetic.draggable is not a method" says FireBug.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a small example?  There have been changes to the Kinetic API.  Here is a draggable image with 3.8.2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/kinetic/kinetic-v3.8.2.js'></script>    
    <script type='text/javascript'>        

      window.onload = function () {

          var stage = new Kinetic.Stage('container', 400, 300);
          var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
              name: 'someLayer'
          });

          var logo = new Image();        
          logo.onload = function() {

              var myImage = new Kinetic.Image({
                    x: stage.width / 2 - (logo.width / 2)
                  , y: stage.height - logo.height - 5
                  , image: logo
                  , width: logo.width
                  , height: logo.height
              });          

              myImage.draggable(true)
              layer.add(myImage);
              layer.draw();
          }
          logo.src = "\./resources/images/ccs_logo.png";        

          stage.add(layer)        
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body onmousedown="return false;" bgcolor=#000000>        
    <div id="container">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Most notably, configs were recently introduced for class instantiation.  A Kinetic rectangle used to be defined like so:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rectangle(function () {

    //do drawing stuff here
});
```

But now it is defined with a config (an object literal):

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rectangle({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    height: 20,
    width: 20
});
```

You can see examples in the [docs](http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Rect.php); also check out the updated [KineticJS Tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rect-tutorial/).